# Session does not giving right records?

Tags: nhibernate, orm

I want to keep one session, but when I rollback transaction then transaction gets isActive=false, so I can not commit and rollback in next statements by using same transaction. then I need to create new transaction but what is going wrong here ?

```
        var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession();/* It returns new session. */
        var transaction1 = session.BeginTransaction();
        var list1 = session.Query<Make>().ToList(); /* It returs 4 records. */
        session.Delete(list1[2]);

        /* After Rollback, transaction is isActive=false so I can not commit 
         * and rollback from this transaction in future. so I need to create new transaction.
         */
        transaction1.Rollback();

        var transaction2 = session.BeginTransaction();

        /* It returns 3 records. 
         * I am not getting object(which was deleted but after that rollback) here why ? 
         */
        var list2 = session.Query<Make>().ToList();
```

Anyone have idea what is going wrong here ? I am not getting deleted object which was rollback.

Comment: There is a reason I edited your tags. There are no mappings at all in your question; why are you adding **three** mapping-related tags?

Comment: Hello Diego, I am using fluent-nhibernate so I want to keep fluent-nhibernate tag also with this.

Comment: Fluent NHibernate is just a mapping method. There are no mappings here, and your problems is not related to mappings anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flushing means that NHibernate will make sure that all changes are persisted to the DB.
That is, it will make sure that all necessary SQL statements are executed keep session in sync to DB.
ISession will execute the SQL statements needed to synchronize the ADO.NET connection's state with the state of objects held in memory.

In your case : When the transaction is Rollback, all those changes will be reverted but still the session is not synchronised to DB.

So Session.Flush() will do this.

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-endingsession

Comment: Have you checked with my code that is with question ? Could you please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out, but the solution is quite easy.

Since there is no `Flush` within `transaction1`, the SQL `DELETE` is being automatically executed inside `transaction2`, before the `SELECT`.

This behavior is expected.

Comment: Thank you Diego to look into this, could you tell me where should be flush in above code to get expected result. You help really solve my lot of issue.

Comment: Flush before the rollback. But I must say the usage pattern is really odd.

Comment: Yes, you should avoid code like that. Consider if you change a loaded object "during" the first transaction, then flush, then rollback. Now the object in memory will still show the modified state while the database will have the original state. During the following transaction, the changed state may affect the outcome of some decision, despite this changed state not being persisted. Usually, aborting a transaction is only done when some error happens, and you should wipe/recreate the session too.

Comment: Thanks Diego, it works. but I have some questions : 1. could you tell me why it happens ? 2. Can we have multiple transactions within single session ? 3. Should we close session after rollback or commit then create new session and transaction for next work. ?

Comment: 1. What else do you want to know? 2. Yes. 3. You can commit multiple times, but if you are rolling back, you should be closing your session too. Rollbacks are not (should not be) part of the normal flow.